# Create a Query using QueryBuilder with two Many-to-Many relation in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, query-builder

Good evening everybody!

I have got a problem with the QueryBuilder in Symfony2.

A USER can be part of some GROUPS. Each GROUP can access to CATEGORIES. Here is a little database diagram.

[image: Database diagram]

Now, I would like to retrieve Categories for a User with the QueryBuilder in order to put the result in a form thanks to my CategoryRepository. Here is the corresponding SQL Statement (in the example I put 1 for the user_id but it is provided by `$user->getId()` in the CategoryRepository.

```
SELECT theCategoryObject
FROM category C, category_group CG, group G, user_group UG, user U
WHERE FU.id = 1
AND U.user_id = UG.user_id
AND UG.group_id = G.group_id
AND CG.group_id = G.group_id
AND CG.category_id = C.category_id
```

I tried to use EXISTS and MEMBER OF but it does not filter anything.

```
public function findByUserQueryBuilder(User $user)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->where('c.isSelectionable = true');

    foreach ($user->getGroups() as $group)
    {
        $qb->andWhere('EXISTS (SELECT ' . $group->getId() . ' FROM ISIMA\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Group g' . $group->getId() . ' WHERE g' . $group->getId() . ' MEMBER OF c.groups)');
    }
    return $qb;
}
```

Thanks for your future answers !

Comment: What have your tried with respect to DQL?  It's almost the same.

Comment: I think that it could be a little bit prettier with a QueryBuilder no ? I can turn my SQL statement into DQL statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution ! I forgot to define the group Id and place an Or condition in case of the User is part of several groups.

```
public function findByUserQueryBuilder(User $user)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->where('c.isSelectionable = true')

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($user->getGroups() as $group)
    {
        $query = 'EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ISIMA\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Group g' . $group->getId() . ' WHERE g' . $group->getId() . '.id = ' . $group->getId() . ' AND g' . $group->getId() . ' MEMBER OF c.groups)';
        if($i == 0)
        {
            $qb->andWhere($query);
            $i = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $qb->orWhere($query);
        }
    }
    return $qb;
}
```